# Does JavaScript not work on data URI pages in WebKit?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, webkit, data-uri

On Chrome on Android, JavaScript on a `data` URI page consisting of the following HTML

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:alert('Hi.');">Say hi</a>
</body>
</html>
```

would result in a dialog box being saying "Hi." shown when I click "Say hi". In Chrome on iOS, however, nothing happens. Does JavaScript not work on `data` URI pages in WebKit browsers on iOS?